# Can a question starting with "how" be answered with a "when" reply?

Tags: word-usage

> So how did this lying issue start? Well, it began the
>   night of my wedding.

Can I answer that "how" question in that way? If not, what would be a better option?

(Now that I think of it, I'm not sure if the answer is a "when" answer.)

Comment: "How did you meet her?" ~ "When we were at university together we were in the same class"

Comment: So it's OK to answer with when?

Comment: In some circumstances, yes. I understand why you are asking the question - how should be answered by explaining the means, not by giving a time, but a context where the means is by being at the right time and place is not impossible.

Comment: Often the statement of the time is just the beginning of the answer, and you'll continue by describing the circumstances, which answers the "how" question. BTW, did you stop lying when you removed all the weeds?

Comment: @Barmar Haha, didn't notice. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it's fine if the narrator goes on to explain how the lying started, and uses the "when" answer to let the reader know the context. For example:

> So how did this lying issue start? Well, it began the night of my wedding. She told me she put some beer in the fridge, so I checked and there was none!

Comment: No beer!?  I hope you filed for an annulment right away!